# Force HTTPS WWW and Add Trailing Slash to All URLS

Tags: redirect

I'm trying to avoid multiple redirects. My current set up includes the following:

```
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
       RewriteRule ^\/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1[R=301,L]
       RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}[L,R=301]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
       RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

What I need is a rule that forces HTTPS, WWW and adds the trailing slash to all urls with one rule.

The above is forcing the urls to run through two redirects.

I've searched everywhere and was able to find one rule for https / www and remove trailing slash in one rule, but not one for adding the slash.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/08/redirect-domain-http-https-www-apache/ the answer appears to be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

You can have multiple conditions before each rule.

Alternatively just change the `[L]` flag in your existing RewriteRules to `[N]` to process all your rules in one go.

Comment: Thank you! I also need the trailing slash to all urls. This doesn't seem to do that.